# Why does g++ give file not recognized error?

Tags: g++

`g++ .scratch` gives

```
.scratch: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There seems to be the issue with extension because trying `g++ scratch.cpp` works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g++` seems to require specific extensions to detect the file format (here `.cpp` for C++ source file).